# give link to sentence to open image in fancybox in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, fancybox

I want to invoke an image in a FancyBox modal window when a user clicks on a certain word on my Wordpress site. Are there any suggested plugins or methods?

**For Example:**

```
This is sentence and want to give link to THIS WORD.
```

> By clicking on **THIS WORD** it should open image in fancy box. I have 10
>   different words and want to open 10 different images in fancy box.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fancybox installed and working, adding the class "fancybox" to any link (a-tag) will open the link in a fancybox. Example (HTML-Code):

```
This is sentence and want to give link to 
<a href="this_image.jpg" class="fancybox" title="Open image in pop-up">THIS WORD</a>.
```

(The title-attribute may be omitted.)